# Install Reference Assemblies for .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to run a legacy project for detecting USB devices on the computer, but the software was written a long time ago and also using .NET framework 4.0 which is now outdated. However, Microsoft still allows you to use version 4.5, but you have to reference the assemblies of the project.

[image]

That's where the problem begins. Firstly, no matter what I do, I can't find any instructions on how this is done. I initially selected the Reference file and right clicked for the option to add references, but the reference list is empty.

[image]
No matter what I am trying to do, it seems like version 4.0 keeps evading me. I added some photos for context.

If you can provide a solution that would be much appreciated, or a link for downloading the .NET 4.0 framework

I tried looking for a .NET 4.0 download to go around this problem, but apparently Microsoft doesn't offer it anymore, only a link to an article about using and adding reference assemblies, which I could not understand.

[image]

Comment: The error message is showing that you're targeting .NET 4.8 - not 4.0 or 4.5. That's probably the best thing to do anyway, but you do need to look for the right thing. Just download the .NET 4.8 SDK and you should be fine. (I'd expect updating to the latest version of Visual Studio to include it automatically...)

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-developer-pack-offline-installer

Comment: You can right-click your project in Visual Studio's explorer and click Properties to see what your target framework is. Because according to the information you provided, it should be that your computer does not have .net framework 4.8 installed. Of course, if you are sure that your project requires .net framework 4.0, then just install it directly.

Answer (score 1):

- Follow the link https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48
- Next download and install the develop pack

  [image: Next download and install the develop pack]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34138718)

Comment: @wohlstad In this case, it is an instruction to download and install something, so it is not a link-only answer. The link serves as the source of where to download, and the image an additional help to see what you need to choose. In other words it is an answer, and should not be deleted.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel understood. The answer was flagged for review and seemed like a link-only one.